# Here Tracking could not add a device

Tags: here-api

I register to the 90 trial period with here tracking. I try to register a new device through app.tracking.here.com but after waiting 30 seconds I always get the message couldn't add the device.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the website from your Android device to get device id. It wont work if you are trying from a non Android device eg: computer, laptop etc.

You can read more details on using the tracker app here: developer.here.com/blog/introducing-here-tracking

Update: 
If mobile browser still not helping you, then download the HERE Tracker app from the Google Play store to start out creating some test data. In the web app, use the Device Management screen to add a new device.

This issue has been fixed and is working now for Android devices

Comment: I am getting the same error from an Android device (chrome browser). I see the following network requests to   https://tracking.api.here.com/registry/v2/ef578afd-7494-4007-95a9-2ce6e9725ae9/status  always returning  the following response {"percent":0,"status":"started"}. Seems to be polling this endpoint for 30 seconds and then giving the error message:  Couldn't add the device.

Comment: Please try to download the HERE Tracker app from the Google Play store to start out creating some test data. In the web app, use the Device Management screen to add a new device.

Comment: With the HERE Tracker app the first screen says: "Using a web browser on another device, go to app.tracking.here.com, sign in to you HERE account and select select "Add device". When you the the QR code on the website, tap "Scan QR" .... "  . So this is what I am doing but the register device is not working from https://app.tracking.here.com/?action=setup-device.  Could you tell me if you are able to reproduce the issue?  Can something be wrong with my account ?

Comment: Yes, currently we are getting errors in web browser, but it works fine in mobile web browsers. While we try to work on this, please try to get the QR code from app.tracking.here.com by login into another mobile web browser and scan it into your app in android device. We tested this and it works. Provide your screenshots if it still doesnt work for you.

Comment: Hi this issue is still happening and I have tried on different mobile browsers. The network activity show that the status endpoint always returns  status=started and percent=0. It looks like a backend error and not a browser error.  In which web browser and version do you say it works?  Is there an alternative way to register a device  that is working beside using mobile browsers which is not working for me. Thanks

Comment: We regret to inform that this functionality on web for the time being is disabled. We will be back soon.

Answer (score 0):

I tried from Android: default browser, Chrome and Firefox, but I always get the same error. I am using Android 8.0

[Screenshot: Add a device from Android browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdwyu.jpg)